# Nesting XML elements with FOR XML, PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

I have a table EVENTS:

```
Name    Event       Gift        Label
Jeff    Birthday    Card        Happy Birthday
Jeff    Birthday    Present     Jeff's prezzy
Maisey  Promotion   Cake        Well Done!
Maisey  Birthday    Card        Happy Birthday
Maisey  Birthday    Cake        Another Year Older!
```

Here's the code to produce that table:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    [name] VARCHAR(250),
    [event] VARCHAR(250),
    [gift] VARCHAR(250),
    [label] VARCHAR(2500)
);

INSERT INTO @TempTable([name], [event], [gift], [label]) VALUES
('Jeff','Birthday','Card','Happy Birthday'),
('Jeff','Birthday','Present','Jeff`s prezzy'),
('Maisey','Promotion','Cake','Well Done!'),
('Maisey','Birthday','Card','Happy Birthday'),
('Maisey','Birthday','Cake','Another Year Older!')
```

Which I would like to generate the following XML from:

```
<celebrations>
    <person name="Jeff">
        <events>
            <event name="Birthday">
                <gifts>
                    <gift name="Card" Value="Happy Birthday" />
                    <gift name="Present" Value="Jeff's prezzy" />
                </gifts>
            </event>
        </events>
    </person>
    <person name="Maisey">
        <events>
            <event name="Promotion">
                <gifts>
                    <gift name="Cake" value="Well Done!" />
                </gifts>
            </event>
            <event name="Birthday">
                <gifts>
                    <gift name="Card" value="Happy Birthday" />
                    <gift name="Cake" value="Another Year Older!" />
                </gifts>
            </event>
        </events>
    </person>
</celebrations>
```

My current SQLXML looks like this:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT (
                SELECT T1.*
                FOR XML path('')
                    ,root('gifts')
                    ,type
                )
        FROM @TempTable AS T1
        FOR XML path('person')
            ,type
        )
FOR XML path('persons')
```

Which is currently producing this:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <gifts>
      <name>Jeff</name>
      <event>Birthday</event>
      <gift>Card</gift>
      <label>Happy Birthday</label>
    </gifts>
  </person>
  <person>
    <gifts>
      <name>Jeff</name>
      <event>Birthday</event>
      <gift>Present</gift>
      <label>Jeff`s prezzy</label>
    </gifts>
  </person>
  <person>
    <gifts>
      <name>Maisey</name>
      <event>Promotion</event>
      <gift>Cake</gift>
      <label>Well Done!</label>
    </gifts>
  </person>
  <person>
    <gifts>
      <name>Maisey</name>
      <event>Birthday</event>
      <gift>Card</gift>
      <label>Happy Birthday</label>
    </gifts>
  </person>
  <person>
    <gifts>
      <name>Maisey</name>
      <event>Birthday</event>
      <gift>Cake</gift>
      <label>Another Year Older!</label>
    </gifts>
  </person>
</persons>
```

How do I format it to look like the XML in the portion at the top of this post?

Comment: It would be great if you'd provided your declared table as *copy-and-paste* MCVE...

Comment: Done. Sorry! You know what it's like with tabs...

Comment: Thx, much better like this... (+1 from my side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, the magic is the *correlated sub-query* with `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    [name] VARCHAR(250),
    [event] VARCHAR(250),
    [gift] VARCHAR(250),
    [label] VARCHAR(2500)
);

INSERT INTO @TempTable([name], [event], [gift], [label]) VALUES
('Jeff','Birthday','Card','Happy Birthday'),
('Jeff','Birthday','Present','Jeff`s prezzy'),
('Maisey','Promotion','Cake','Well Done!'),
('Maisey','Birthday','Card','Happy Birthday'),
('Maisey','Birthday','Cake','Another Year Older!')

SELECT t1.[Name] AS [@name]
      ,(
        SELECT T2.[Event] AS [@name]
              ,(
                SELECT T3.gift AS [@name], T3.label AS [@value]
                FROM @TempTable T3
                WHERE T1.[Name]=T3.[Name] AND T2.[event] = T3.[event]
                GROUP BY T3.gift, T3.label
                FOR XML PATH('gift'),ROOT('gifts'),TYPE
               )
        FROM @TempTable T2
        WHERE T1.[Name]=T2.[Name]
        GROUP BY T2.[event]
        FOR XML PATH('event'),ROOT('events'),TYPE
       ) 
FROM @TempTable AS T1
GROUP BY t1.[Name]
FOR XML PATH('person'),ROOT('celebrations'),TYPE;
```

The result

```
<celebrations>
  <person name="Jeff">
    <events>
      <event name="Birthday">
        <gifts>
          <gift name="Card" value="Happy Birthday" />
          <gift name="Present" value="Jeff`s prezzy" />
        </gifts>
      </event>
    </events>
  </person>
  <person name="Maisey">
    <events>
      <event name="Birthday">
        <gifts>
          <gift name="Cake" value="Another Year Older!" />
          <gift name="Card" value="Happy Birthday" />
        </gifts>
      </event>
      <event name="Promotion">
        <gifts>
          <gift name="Cake" value="Well Done!" />
        </gifts>
      </event>
    </events>
  </person>
</celebrations>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Hope you don't mind, but I added the label->value field to complete the required output. Now I just have to go figure out how you did it ;)